# How can I get Python to find ffprobe?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, path, subprocess, pythonpath

I have `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` installed on my mac (macOS Sierra), and I have added their path to PATH. I can run them from terminal.

I am trying to use `ffprobe` to get the width and height of a video file using the following code:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import json


# function to find the resolution of the input video file
def findVideoResolution(pathToInputVideo):
    cmd = "ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams"
    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    args.append(pathToInputVideo)
    # run the ffprobe process, decode stdout into utf-8 & convert to JSON
    ffprobeOutput = subprocess.check_output(args).decode('utf-8')
    ffprobeOutput = json.loads(ffprobeOutput)

    # find height and width
    height = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['height']
    width = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['width']

    return height, width

h, w = findVideoResolution("/Users/tomburrows/Documents/qfpics/user1/order1/movie.mov")
print(h, w)
```

I am sorry I cannot provide a MCVE, as I didn't write this code, and I don't really know how it works.

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tomburrows/Dropbox/Moviepy Tests/get_dimensions.py", line 21, in <module>
    h, w = findVideoResolution("/Users/tomburrows/Documents/qfpics/user1/order1/movie.mov")
  File "/Users/tomburrows/Dropbox/Moviepy Tests/get_dimensions.py", line 12, in findVideoResolution
    ffprobeOutput = subprocess.check_output(args).decode('utf-8')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe'
```

If python is not reading from the PATH file, how can I specify where `ffprobe` is?

**Edit:**
It appears the python path is not aligned with my shell path.
Using `os.environ["PATH"]+=":/the_path/of/ffprobe/dir"` at the beginning of each program allows me to use ffprobe, but why might my python path not be the same as my shell path?

Comment: To verify that it's indeed a `$PATH` related problem, why not give the full path instead of relying on the shell environment to do it for you? E.g. use `cmd = "/full/path/to/ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import os
print os.environ['PATH']
```

to verify/validate that ffprobe is in your python environment. According to the error you have, it is likely not.

Comment: Yes, the output of your code does not have the path to ffmpeg that appears when I run 'echo $PATH' from the terminal.  How do I update the python path then?

Comment: to temporary solve the issue, add the ffprobe path to the python environment, that is, add *os.environ["PATH"]+=":/the_path/of/ffprobe/dir"*.
However, you should consider why the python path is not aligned with your shell path.

Comment: @Burns: System PATH and Python PYTHONPATH have absolutely nothing to do with each other. 
You need to change PATH so that your command (ffmpeg) can be run from any directory. 
Google 'how to change PATH' for your particular shell.