# Using FFProbe within a Python script

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am fairly new to python, this is my first real project and I have come to a roadblock. What I have here is a .wmv file, I am using FFprobe to extract the duration in seconds from the .wmv file. When I run the following command in the CMD:

```
ffprobe -i Video2.wmv -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

I get successful output.

However, when I use os.system, like this:

```
os.system('ffprobe -i Video2.wmv -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"')
```

I get the following output:

```
'ffprobe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This is very confusing and I haven't been able to find a fix to this exact problem online, any input would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at some of my questions, I have been doing a very similar thing. Especially [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285142/how-can-i-get-python-to-find-ffprobe).

Comment: Where is ffprobe stored on your computer?

Comment: @Gloin It is located in C:\ffmpeg

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @Gloin I just went to the ffmpeg website and used their installer. I dropped my ffmpeg files in the C drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can't find ffprobe because it isn't in your environment variables. [This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcdTIDHm4KM) shows how to properly install it, as does [this wikihow page](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows)) (method 2), which I'll quote from here:

> ### Enabling FFmpeg in the Command Line
>
> [image]
>   Click the Start button and right-click on Computer. Select Properties
>   from the right-click menu. In the System window, click on the
>   “Advanced system settings” link in the left frame.
>
> [image]
>
> Click the Environmental Variables button in the System Properties
>   window. It will be located at the bottom of the window.
>
> [image]
>
> Select the PATH entry in the "User variables" section. This is located
>   in the first frame in the Environmental Variables window. Click the
>   Edit button. In the “Variable value” field, enter ;c:\ffmpeg\bin after
>   anything that's already written there. If you copied it to a different
>   drive, change the drive letter. Click OK to save your changes. If
>   anything is entered incorrectly in this screen, it could cause Windows
>   to be unable to boot properly. If there is no PATH entry in the "User
>   variables" setting, click the New button and create one. Enter PATH
>   for the variable name. This method will enable FFmpeg for the current
>   user. Other Windows users will not be able to run it from the command
>   line. To enable it for everyone, enter ;c:\ffmpeg\bin in the PATH
>   entry in "System variables". Be very careful not to delete anything
>   that is already in this variable.
>
> [image]
>
> Open the command prompt. Enter the command “ffmpeg –version”. If the
>   command prompt returns the version information for FFmpeg, then the
>   installation was successful, and FFmpeg can be accessed from any
>   folder in the command prompt.
>
> If you receive a “libstdc++ -6 is
>   missing” error, you may need to install the Microsoft Visual C++
>   Redistributable Package, which is available for free from Microsoft.

I hope that helps.

Just a side note, I don't think that `os.system` is the recommended way of calling the command line like that any more.

I'd recommend something more like this using subprocess instead (adapted from code [here](https://gist.github.com/oldo/dc7ee7f28851922cca09)):

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import json
def get_duration(file_path_with_file_name):

    cmd = 'ffprobe -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"'
    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    args.append(file_path_with_file_name)
    # run the ffprobe process, decode stdout into utf-8 & convert to JSON
    ffprobe_output = subprocess.check_output(args).decode('utf-8')

    ffprobe_output = json.loads(ffprobe_output)

    return ffprobe_output
```

Comment: @mattp341 Your welcome. I've just fixed an error in my suggested script at the end, in case you want to use it